# Why can't I set "modprobe vfio enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode=1"?

Tags: kernel, 22.04, virtualization, qemu, modprobe

Running Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-83 inside a QEMU VM:

```
guest$ sudo modprobe vfio enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode=1
guest$ cat /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode
N
```

It's not changed. I've also set the kernel boot parameters to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=pt intel_iommu=on"
```

On the Host OS, also Ubuntu 22.04, the above works fine:

```
host$ sudo modprobe vfio enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode=1
host$ cat /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode
Y
```

Furthermore, I also installed a CentOS 7 in a separate VM, and the above two lines work, so it's not a fundamental VM thing. Where should I be looking to see why the `modprobe` is not giving me the desired result?

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial from RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/hands-vhost-user-warm-welcome-dpdk) but using Ubuntu rather than CentOS as the Guest.